# What to do with the silverlight tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

So Moonlight development stopped in 2011, and the Moonlight plugin is mostly useless today. (It is even not possible to install it to Firefox without modifying the plugin.) So I think we could say that Moonlight is dead.

On the site we have a [moonlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/moonlight) and a [silverlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/silverlight) tag, but the latter is still the synonym of the former: [link](https://askubuntu.com/tags/moonlight/synonyms)

> The following tags will be remapped to [moonlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/moonlight):
>   [silverlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/silverlight)

That's obviously wrong: When a new question comes in about silverlight, and the ASKer correctly tags it as [silverlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/silverlight), the system will automatically retag it as [moonlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/moonlight).

So what to do with the [silverlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/silverlight) tag?

- Leave it as it is now? (I guess not.)
- Break the connection, and let the [silverlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/silverlight) tag orphan? (I think this would be the best, but then we would start the new era with 0 questions with the [silverlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/silverlight) tag)
- Remap the tag to the newly created [pipelight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/pipelight) tag? (That's neither good I think.)
- Revise all the questions with [moonlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/moonlight) and tag them correctly as [silverlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/silverlight) or [moonlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/moonlight)?
- Anything else?

---

*I will do the retaging if no-one else wants (there is under 50 questions with the moonlight tag).*

---

BUMP. (Sorry.) Please someone break the synonymity between [moonlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/moonlight) and [silverlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/silverlight). [Just happened again](https://askubuntu.com/posts/400401/revisions) that a correctly tagged question as [silverlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/silverlight) was automatically retagged as [moonlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/moonlight). (Mateo corrected that problem by removing the [moonlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/moonlight) tag)

Comment: So I think there was enough time to vote, and it is obvious that the synonymy between moonlight and silverlight has to be deleted. (It is like a bug.) So I ask a moderator/high-rep user to please clear that synonym thing, so we or I can retag the questions correctly. As most of the few people who voted voted for that option. But I can't retag until the synonym is in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Revise all the questions with [moonlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/moonlight) and tag them correctly as [silverlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/silverlight) or [moonlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/moonlight).**

Comment: This and the one asking for the synonymization to be removed are the same.

Comment: @Braiam My other answer (which of course wasn't clear in that way, but now became the same as this one.) tried to mean the possibility, to just simply delete the synonimity but not revise the questions already tagged with moonlight. So we would start a new era with zero questions tagged as silverlight. Unfortunately that answer wasn't clear on its own, and after your edit it became the same as this one. Now I don't know If I should edit an answer which was already voted to mean something else. (?) But it is clear that the majority wants the deletion of the synonymity.

Answer (score 2):

- **Break the connection between [silverlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/silverlight) and [moonlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/moonlight), each of them is about something different.**

Answer (score 0):

- **Leave it as it is now.**

Answer (score -3):

- **Remap the tag to the newly created [pipelight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/pipelight) tag.** (make pipelight and silverlight synonyms)